# List of mock valid/invalid Email Addresses for Unit Tests

Tags: unit-testing, language-agnostic, email-validation, test-data

Does anyone know of a list of email addresses (which don’t need to be real) I can use for an email validation assembly for a unit test?

I’ve been looking for such a list and can’t seem to find one. I’m not looking for real addresses, just ones that fit, and the more things I can throw at the test the better. I’ve got 10 right now, but if there is a list, it would give me a more thorough test.

Answer (score 26):

I believe you were looking for something like this:

[List of Valid and Invalid Email Addresses](http://codefool.tumblr.com/post/15288874550/list-of-valid-and-invalid-email-addresses)

Answer (score 5):

Check the tests of the Apache Commons EmailValidator class:

- [`EmailTest`](https://github.com/apache/commons-validator/blob/master/src/test/java/org/apache/commons/validator/EmailTest.java),
- [`EmailValidatorTest`](https://github.com/apache/commons-validator/blob/master/src/test/java/org/apache/commons/validator/routines/EmailValidatorTest.java).

The [`EmailValidatorTest`](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-validator/blob/master/engine/src/test/java/org/hibernate/validator/test/internal/constraintvalidators/hv/EmailValidatorTest.java) in the Hibernate Validator also contains some address.

Comment: The first two links are broken, BTW. Been a while since this post. :)

Answer (score 3):

I like to use the set in [this page on email validating regexes](http://fightingforalostcause.net/misc/2006/compare-email-regex.php) because the addresses contain what they're testing inside the email address.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a set of test emails that Dominic Sayers uses to test his isEmail validator:

http://code.iamcal.com/php/rfc822/tests/

For more on isEmail:

http://isemail.info/about

Comment: That list you've linked to looks quite useful at first glance, but your (overly brief) answer seems to pull that list out of its context. Could you comment a little on it? For example, what "test suite" or project does it belong to? What do the "Expected" / "Strict Mode" / "Public Mode" columns mean? Is it up-to-date? etc.

Comment: No, it's not out of context.  Sayer's tool has a DSN lookup feature.  http://isemail.info/about.  https://code.google.com/p/isemail/issues/list.

Comment: Having said that, @Alex, it's always best to give a bit of context when giving an answer so that it's not a link-only answer.